# Open new terminal window and execute bash file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I have written a bash script 'A' that executes some commands,but after complete execution of script 'A',I want another bash script 'B' which is stored on desktop to be executed new terminal window after execution of 'A' is completed.What command should I write at end of script 'A'?So that script 'B' is executed in new terminal window. I have tried many commands such as `gnome-terminal` and `konsole` both with their various arguments but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Why you need to execute in new terminal?

Comment: Try xterm or rxvt.

Comment: I'm running a project where I need to two different terminal windows running different tasks @hamzatuna

Comment: can you explain that @IporSircer

Comment: `rxvt -e <command>`, `xterm -e <command>`

Comment: I am interested in this answer because I'd like to tail a bunch of log files in different terminal windows (apache log, system log, etc...)  A bonus would be to set the label line at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Say two commands instead of Script A and Script B I use `ls -lh` and `echo`

```sh
xterm -e "ls -lh; read ;xterm -e \"echo \"Hello_World\"; read \""
```

`read` is given just to stimulate human interaction and you can see the terminal appearing and closing.